# Semantic-UI-React Dropdown Selected Index

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I am trying to set a default selected item in a semantic-ui-react dropdown. If I select an item from the dropdown, when I reopen the dropdown it opens on the correct item. However, this item is persisted, and when I refresh the page, the correct items are displayed on the dropdown, but it does not open on the correct item.

Please advise.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: Once you refresh the page, the whole code is fetched again. In other words, all values are reset. So if you want anything to be persistent, do not refresh the page. If you still insist on making it persistent, you might have to change how the value is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7713928/matt-koevort), it sounds like you are only using the internal component state. Whatever your components initialize with, they will always start that same way. Your entire React application works this way. If you are expecting your data to be persistent, it needs to be stored somewhere. When you refresh you are starting over again. If the state of your application is not being put elsewhere, you lose that state every single time you refresh because the only copy of state is in your client browser.

Basically you currently only have a frontend application that is not storing data anywhere. Depending on your needs, you could do this in a lot of different ways. A REST API. A GraphQL API. One simple way to accomplish this if you are just creating a simple website would be to use a headless CMS. That will give you a database to store your application data. There are [a lot of interesting ones out there that you can explore based on your needs](https://www.google.com/search?q=headless%20cms%20react&oq=headless%20cms%20react).